# Touch zoom with fling effect?

Tags: wpf, touch

Implementing touch functionality in `WPF` is relatively easy. Set `IsManipulationEnabled="True"` and handle `ManipulationDelta` to apply the transform. For translation, `WPF` seems to support flinging. If you handle `ManipulationInertiaStarting` you can set desired velocities.

Now, flinging in X/Y direction is nice, but I want to fling when zooming too (Z direction). Is this supported in `WPF`?

E.g. Snapping your fingers on the screen would zoom until the expansion velocity has reached zero. As it is now, it stops immediately when my fingers leave the screen.

**This does not work**:

```
private void OnManipulationInertiaStarting(object sender, ManipulationInertiaStartingEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    //
    // Decrease the velocity of the Rectangle's resizing by 
    // 0.1 inches per second every second.
    // (0.1 inches * 96 DIPS per inch / (1000ms^2)
    e.ExpansionBehavior = new InertiaExpansionBehavior()
    {
        InitialVelocity = e.InitialVelocities.ExpansionVelocity,
        DesiredDeceleration = 0.1 * 96 / 1000.0 * 1000.0
    };

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lester Lobo [has a post that might help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/12/21/wpf-manipulation-basics.aspx).  Although, looking at your code, you may have seen the post already.

Comment: Thanks, but that sample shows the same problem (so it's actually a good start to try this out). Zooming stops immediately when you no longer touch the screen,